# Can nginx redirect instead of proxy

Tags: node.js, redirect, nginx, websocket, load-balancing

Suppose I have 1 nginx server and many Websocket servers:

```
server1.exmaple.com
server2.example.com
server3.example.com
```

When there is only a few concurrent connection Nginx can handle the traffic to and from the servers using **upstream** and **proxy_pass**.

Because users can send much more Websocket message than HTTP request in a given time, there is going to be a turning point when Nginx can't handle anymore message because it is out of network resources.
Adding more upstream servers won't help because the bottleneck is the server all users conenct to, the Nginx server.

If Nginx can do redirection when the Websocket handshake happens the browser can use that direct connection to each server and leave Nginx out of this.
If these servers can't handle the traffic I can just add more.

Is it possible to do redirection with Nginx instead of proxying, I can't find any demo or documentation about it?

Comment: Have you reached that point? Or at least did you benchmark?

Comment: Haven't yet, but benchmarked it on a small 1 cpu server and I am afraid it can't handle a ddos websocket attack. If the traffic would go directly to the servers I could deploy a few more in a similar situation, but if I use proxy the only way is to upgrade the Nginx server for more core.

Comment: There are other means to mitigate ddos attacks. Nginx's upstreams are not meant for this.